# Estimating $\tau$ (cognitive hierarchy)

Tags: econometrics, behavioral-economics

I am a little confused about how the parameter $\tau$ is usually estimated in a [cognitive hierarchy](http://faculty.haas.berkeley.edu/hoteck/PAPERS/CH1.pdf) model (recall that $\tau$ is the mean number of 'thinking steps'). For example, suppose that subjects play [Arad and Rubinstein](https://www.aeaweb.org/articles?id=10.1257/aer.102.7.3561)'s 11/20 game and that their choices are:

Subject 1: 20 (corresponding to 'level 0')

Subject 2: 19 (corresponding to 'level 1')

Subject 3: 18 (corresponding to 'level 2')

How could we then estimate $\tau$ (e.g. using maximum likelihood methods)?

*My thoughts on this (added):* Of course, it is easy to find a $\tau$ that maximises the likelihood of the data. In this example, the likelihood is
$$
\text{P(first player is level 0)}\times \text{P(second player is level 1})\times \text{P(third player is level 2})
$$
or (using the assumption that the levels are Poisson distributed with mean $\tau$)
$$
e^{-\tau}\tau^0/0! \times e^{-\tau}\tau^1/1! \times e^{-\tau}\tau^2/2!
$$
Maximising the likelihood is then equivalent to maximising
$$
e^{-3\tau}\tau^3
$$
which then yields a maximiser $\tau = 1$ (note that we have perfectly matched the average level of the participants, even though the estimator was not chosen to match this moment). However, this procedure totally ignores the constraint that every type (level) optimises given their beliefs about the distribution of levels below them. Is this is problem -- or is it somehow OK to totally ignore this constraint?